# Delphi Timer on different Windows OS

Tags: delphi

timer is set to one second

```
  procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      caption := Format('%s', [FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', Frac(GetTime))])
    end;
```

On windows XP and win 8 i will get every second value exactly increased by one second. On windows 7 will be more. Why? How to get on Windows 7 constant value increased by only one second?

Comment: Because of the reason explained in [`the first paragraph here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: what about XP and Win 8? There is diffrent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUI timers are not precise in the sense that they do not fire periodically. They promise to fire no more frequently than the interval that you specify. However, they may fire less frequently.

The simple solution is to make your timer fire a little more rapidly. You need updates every second, so make the timer fire every 10Hz, say. That will have the effect of smoothing over the imprecision of the GUI timer.